# Ejabberd not allowing registration from client

Tags: cluster, xmpp, ejabberd

I've got an ejabber cluster setup. When trying to register a user with a client (say Adium) I'm getting a 503: Service Unavailable error. I'm running ejabberd 2.1.x

The log shows this:

```
E(<0.389.0>:ejabberd_hooks:335) : {{case_clause,
                                   {value,{access,register,[{allow,all}]}}},
                                  [{gen_mod,get_opt,3},
                                   {mod_register,try_register,5},
                                   {mod_register,process_iq,4},
                                   {mod_register,
                                    unauthenticated_iq_register,4},
                                   {ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4},
                                   {ejabberd_c2s,
                                    process_unauthenticated_stanza,2},
                                   {ejabberd_c2s,wait_for_feature_request,2},
                                   {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10}]}
running hook: {c2s_unauthenticated_iq,
                 ["domain.com",
                  {iq,"purple111a7fa3",set,"jabber:iq:register",[],
                      {xmlelement,"query",
                          [{"xmlns","jabber:iq:register"}],
                          [{xmlelement,"username",[],[{xmlcdata,<<"user">>}]},
                           {xmlelement,"password",[],
                               [{xmlcdata,<<"psd">>}]}]}},
                  {{my local ip},56632}]}
```

`domain.com` is my domain, `user` is the username, `pass` is the password and my local IP is the local IP of the machine I'm on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Turns out it was an issue with the configuration file.  We upgraded from 2.1.3 to 2.1.x and everything seemed cool.  Guess it ran, but some stuff was messed up.

Found http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Ejabberd_Configuration that had a sample config. Modded it up with our info, and our extras, and everything is cream now.